# Would it be considered "pythonic" to use a nested defaultdict where bottom level is defaulted to 0 for counting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api, defaultdict

I am building something to sort and add values from an API response. I ended up going with an interesting structure, and I just want to make sure there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Helps create a unique nested default dict object
# for code readability
def dict_counter():
    return defaultdict(lambda: 0)

# Creates the nested defaultdict object
ad_data = defaultdict(dict_counter)

# Sorts each instance into its channel, and
# adds the dict values incrimentally
for ad in example:   
    # Collects channel and metrics
    channel = ad['ad_group']['type_']
    metrics = dict(
        impressions= int(ad['metrics']['impressions']),
        clicks     = int(ad['metrics']['clicks']),
        cost       = int(ad['metrics']['cost_micros'])
    )
    
    # Adds the variables
    ad_data[channel]['impressions'] += metrics['impressions']
    ad_data[channel]['clicks'] += metrics['clicks']
    ad_data[channel]['cost'] += metrics['cost']
```

The output is as desired. Again, I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel or doing something really inefficient here.

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.dict_counter()>,
            {'DISPLAY_STANDARD': defaultdict(<function __main__.dict_counter.<locals>.<lambda>()>,
                         {'impressions': 14, 'clicks': 4, 'cost': 9}),
             'SEARCH_STANDARD': defaultdict(<function __main__.dict_counter.<locals>.<lambda>()>,
                         {'impressions': 6, 'clicks': 2, 'cost': 4})})
```

Here's what my input data would look like:

```
example = [
    {
        'campaign': 
        {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/campaigns/12345',
            'status': 'ENABLED',
            'name': 'test_campaign_2'
        },
        'ad_group': {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/adGroups/12345',
            'type_': 'DISPLAY_STANDARD'},
        'metrics': {
            'clicks': '1', 'cost_micros': '3', 'impressions': '5'
        },
        'ad_group_ad': {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/adGroupAds/12345~12345',
            'ad': {
                'resource_name': 'customers/12345/ads/12345'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'campaign': 
        {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/campaigns/12345',
            'status': 'ENABLED',
            'name': 'test_campaign_2'
        },
        'ad_group': {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/adGroups/12345',
            'type_': 'SEARCH_STANDARD'},
        'metrics': {
            'clicks': '2', 'cost_micros': '4', 'impressions': '6'
        },
        'ad_group_ad': {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/adGroupAds/12345~12345',
            'ad': {
                'resource_name': 'customers/12345/ads/12345'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'campaign': 
        {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/campaigns/12345',
            'status': 'ENABLED',
            'name': 'test_campaign_2'
        },
        'ad_group': {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/adGroups/12345',
            'type_': 'DISPLAY_STANDARD'},
        'metrics': {
            'clicks': '3', 'cost_micros': '6', 'impressions': '9'
        },
        'ad_group_ad': {
            'resource_name': 'customers/12345/adGroupAds/12345~12345',
            'ad': {
                'resource_name': 'customers/12345/ads/12345'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The only change I would make is to say `defaultdict(int)` instead of using a lamba.  Otherwise, it's hard to argue with success.

Comment: use a Counter for counting it has default as 0, `from collections import Counter`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, IMHO such a question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you have, but the code for copying the values from one dict to another is a bit repetitive and a little vulnerable to mis-pasting a key name.  I'd suggest putting the mapping between the keys in a dict so that there's a single source of truth for what keys you're copying from the input metrics dicts and what keys that data will live under in the output:

```
fields = {
    # Map input metrics dicts to per-channel metrics dicts.
    'impressions': 'impressions',  # same
    'clicks': 'clicks',            # same
    'cost_micros': 'cost',         # different
}
```

Since each dict in your output is going to contain the keys from `fields.values()`, you have the option of creating these as plain dicts with their values initialized to zero rather than as defaultdicts (this doesn't have any major benefits over `defaultdict(int)`, but it does make pretty-printing a bit easier):

```
# Create defaultdict of per-channel metrics dicts.
ad_data = defaultdict(lambda: dict.fromkeys(fields.values(), 0))
```

and then you can do a simple nested iteration to populate `ad_data`:

```
# Aggregate input metrics into per-channel metrics.
for ad in example:   
    channel = ad['ad_group']['type_']
    for k, v in ad['metrics'].items():
        ad_data[channel][fields[k]] += int(v)
```

which for your example input produces:

```
{'DISPLAY_STANDARD': {'impressions': 14, 'clicks': 4, 'cost': 9},
 'SEARCH_STANDARD': {'impressions': 6, 'clicks': 2, 'cost': 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you overthought this one a bit. Consider this simple function that sums two dicts:

```
def add_dicts(a, b):
    return {
        k: int(a.get(k, 0)) + int(b.get(k, 0))
        for k in a | b
    }
```

Using this func, the main loop gets trivial:

```
stats = {}

for obj in example:
    t = obj['ad_group']['type_']
    stats[t] = add_dicts(stats.get(t, {}), obj['metrics'])
```

That's it. No defaultdicts needed.